# Is Fortran 77 supported by GNU gfortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I have come across a book which contains code written in Fortran 77. I wanted to compile and test some of them, and was wondering how well GNU gfortran supports legacy Fortran. I have Ubuntu 14.04 operating system.

Comment: Please use a search engine before posting here. Typing your question's title into google gives you your answer without even having to follow any links, it is right there in the excerpt.

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to the forum. Will do better search next time! :-)

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1):

Yes gfortran allows for fortran 77 see the [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gfortran) standard compile options should work but may give warnings. you can set the flag

```
-std=legacy
```

to disable warnings that are caused from fortran77 features.